# RavenDB Query Multiple Documents Returning 401

Tags: http, ravendb, fiddler

With RavenDB, using Fiddler2, I'm trying to make a request to get multiple documents by ID.  My POST request in fiddler is as follows:

```
url: http://localhost:8080/queries
request body: ['albums/626','albums/631']
```

I'm getting a 401 not authorized error coming back.  Is there a permissions requirement for this operation?  Or am I missing something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to authenticate the request, you can set ravendb to accept anonymous requests by setting "Raven/AnonymousAccess" to "All" in the config file